# Is it possible to have multiple traps for a signal

Tags: ruby, callback, signals, interrupt

I'm trying to understand Ruby's `trap`s for standard signals.

In specific, I'm trying to have multiple signal handlers ("traps") for the same signal. It seems impossible. Here's a super simplified code to demonstrate the problem:

file `traps.rb`:

```
should_stop = false

Signal.trap 'INT' do
  # won't be executed :(
  puts 'int --> A'
  should_stop = true
end

Signal.trap 'INT' do
  # will be executed
  puts 'int --> B'
  should_stop = true
end

times = 0
until should_stop
  puts 'waiting to stop'
  sleep 1
  times += 1
  break if times >= 5
end

puts 'done'
```

Run the code:

```
ruby traps.rb
```

Output without pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
waiting to stop
waiting to stop
waiting to stop
waiting to stop
waiting to stop
done
```

Output with pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after 2 seconds:

```
waiting to stop
waiting to stop
^Cint --> B
done
```

It seems that only the last signal trap to be declared is the one which would be executed.

Is this behavior by design?

If not, how can we have multiple handlers executed to the same signal?

The main reason for asking this is that third party libraries might add their trap to a signal.

If we have two different third party libraries that add their trap to the same signal, only one of them would actually be executed. That's where the fun begins :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57749169/17772) from [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%C3%B6rg-w-mittag) and the documentation, here's a simplified solution:

```
# file traps.rb

should_stop = false

Signal.trap('INT') do
  puts 'int --> A'
  should_stop = true
end

$prev_trap = Signal.trap('INT') do
  puts 'int --> B'
  should_stop = true
  $prev_trap&.call
end

times = 0
until should_stop
  puts 'waiting to stop'
  sleep 1
  times += 1
  break if times >= 5
end

puts 'done'
```

After running `ruby traps.rb`, and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after 3 seconds, the output looks like this:

```
waiting to stop
waiting to stop
waiting to stop
^Cint --> B
int --> A
done
```

Comment: Did you intend for the `$prev_trap = ` to be placed before the first `Signal.trap` statement? If not, I don't see how this can work.

Comment: @iconoclast , the answer demonstrates the code, as is.

Answer (score 4):

> It seems that only the last signal trap to be declared is the one which would be executed.
>
> Is this behavior by design?

It is not very explicit in [the documentation of `Signal::trap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Signal.html#method-c-trap), but it is by design:

> The command or block specifies code to be run when the signal is raised.

Note the use of the singular, and the absence of any mention of something like "The command or block is added to the list of trap handlers to be run when the signal is raised."

It becomes clearer if you look at the [POSIX `trap` shell builtin](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap) after which `Signal::trap` is modeled:

> The action of `trap` shall override a previous action (either default action or one explicitly set).

The [POSIX `sigaction` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) which is the C equivalent to `trap` says more or less the same thing. Note, however, that the `sigaction` function also gives a way of retrieving the function pointer to the old action, so *theoretically*, you could set the action to a function pointer to a new action which uses the function pointer to the old action to call the old action as part of itself, thus in some way chaining the actions.

Note, however, that this would require the old and new action cooperate in some way. Also note that this mode of operation is not modeled by POSIX `trap`.

> If not, how can we have multiple handlers executed to the same signal?

From the documentation:

> trap returns the previous handler for the given signal.

So, `Signal::trap` implements the behavior from `sigaction` that gives you access to the "old" handler. You could save that old handler somewhere and chain the calls by explicitly calling it from your new handler.

Like with `sigaction`, this requires some form of cooperation between the handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. From the documentation: trap returns the previous handler for the given signal. Interesting.

Comment: Oops, I missed that! Nice find.